# Facing 403 forbidden while accessing spring boot app on wildfly 26.0.1

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

I have a spring boot application with out any security enabled and react as front-end both coupled into a single war. the application is deploying successfully but cant able to access the application using localhost:8080 as it is giving 403 forbidden error and while accessing rest end point im facing 404 not found error on wildfly 26.0.1 but the same application is working fine with out any error on wildfly 15.0.1.

i cant able to understand why it is working on older version of wildfly but not in newer version of wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also indicate the context root of your application in the URL.

To know what is the context root of the app you just deployed, go to : http://127.0.0.1:9990/console/index.html#deployments

Then the URL of your project must look like this: localhost:8080/your-context-root/

For better understanding in how to deploy spring boot in wildfly i recommend you this article: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-application-in-wildfly-application-server-b3670c031ad4